# Analysis Services Query Replicas: Load and process only a single data model on primary replica without deleting from replicas?

Tags: azure, ssas, azure-analysis-services

I am in a position where all my data models consume about 16 GB of RAM, but when I go to process I have to flip from an S1 to an S2 as processing some of the models uses 20 GB of RAM.

I would like to be able to process each model on an S1 and then sync the final results back so I can scale out my S1 to two S1, process one model on it to use the 20 of 26 GB and then sync the results back.

Otherwise I have to run an S2 all the time or go offline to scale up to an S2 to process then drop back again.

Is there anyway to process a data model on one Azure AS instance and then move the results back to another?

Backups restore or detach-reattach or something?

Answer (score 0):

Besides this sounding like an extremely home-made approach and very not robust, there is no way you can simply perform a UNION operation between different tabular. In fact, when you load data into Tabular the loading operation includes complex compression operations.
This means that you cannot simply transfer the data without performing compression operations again.

Instead, I would suggest you to handle the problem differently:

- Can you improve the partitions of your data?
- Remove fields that occupy a lot of space and a are useless
- Make sure data type and compression Hint is optimized